# Can I get between Newark Terminals B and C after security?

Tags: airport-security, ewr

My daughter will fly out of terminal C at 8:00pm.  I fly out of Terminal B at 6:45pm. Both from Newark int. airport. We want to spend as much time together as possible. Is there any connections between terminals after security?  Is there Fast Track through Security?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. There is an airside shuttle bus serving all three terminals. It isn't clear what you mean by "Fast Track," however. Please [edit] to clarify what you're thinking of and why you would qualify for such a service (e.g. there are TSA Precheck, CLEAR, and elite frequent flyer priority lines at various airports, but they're all different in how they work).

Comment: You should log in as "Susan" to make edits, rather than creating new accounts; consider [requesting an account merge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous). I would strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance on writing strong questions.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [airside shuttle bus](https://www.newarkairport.com/at-airport/connecting-flights) between the terminals.

> Between Terminals (United Airlines Connections)
>
> United Airlines operates a shuttle bus between Terminals A and C from
>   5:00am to 10:00pm. In addition, **United also operates a shuttle bus
>   connecting Terminal B to Terminals A and C from 10:00am to 10:00pm.**
>   The shuttle bus is available at **gate A28, B67**, and C70 as illustrated
>   in the image above. This service is free and you will not have to go
>   through TSA security again. Please note this shuttle is operated at
>   the sole responsibility of United Airlines and is subject to
>   modification at their discretion.

The Airport has [a service showing the security waiting times on the terminals in real time](https://www.newarkairport.com/security-wait-times). There you can see that the TSA Precheck line is much faster than the general line, probably it's exactly what you mean with fast lane. You can learn more about the TSA Precheck line on [their website](https://www.tsa.gov/precheck)